# jQuery form validator not working with html

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, plugins

jquery form validation not working.

Tried so many ways but its not working and even not showing any errors.

Sorry for posting this much code.

Dont know how to explain it more, i am new with big forms and searched for all the related links and used that to rectify the error but didn't got the expected results.

Here's my html code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Register Yourself</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>NIT Uttarakhand</h1>
    <h2>Alumni</h2>
    <h3>Register Yourself</h3>

    <form id="register">
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" ><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="mname" placeholder="Middle Name" ><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select name="degree" >
          <option value="BT">B.Tech </option>
          <option value="MT">M.Tech </option>
          <option value="PH">PhD </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select name="branch">
          <option value="civ">Civil Engineering </option>
          <option value="cse">Computer Science & Engineering </option>
          <option value="ece">Electronics and Communication Engineering </option>
          <option value="eee">Electrical and Electronics Engineering </option>
          <option value="mec">Mechanical Engineering </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select name="pass_year" >
          <option value="2015">2015</option>
          <option value="2016">2016</option>
          <option value="2017">2017</option>
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="roll_no" placeholder="Roll Number e.g., BT16CSE023" ><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" >
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Mail ID" >
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="present_address" placeholder="Present Address" ><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="permanent_address" placeholder="Permanent Address" ><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook Profile"><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="linkedin" placeholder="Linked In Profile"><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter Profile"><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="github" placeholder="Github Profile"><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username (min 8 characters)" ><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" >
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="password1"  placeholder="Confirm password" >
      </div>
      <div>
        <input class="btn-btn-primary" id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit Details">
      </div>
    </form>

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/register.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's my jquery code:

```
$().ready(function(){
  // Jquery form validator
  $("#register").validate({
    rules:
    {
      fname:{ required:true},
      degree:{ required: true},
      branch:{ required: true},
      pass_year:{ required: true},
      roll_no:{ required: true, minlength: 10, maxlength: 10 },
      phone:{ required: true, minlength: 10, maxlength: 10 },
      email:{ required: true, email: true },
      present_address:{required:true},
      permanent_address:{required:true},
      facebook:{ url: true},
      linkedin:{ url: true},
      twitter:{ url: true},
      github:{ url: true},
      username:{ required: true, minlength: 8},
      password:{ required: true, minlength: 8 },
      password1:{ required: true, equalTo: "#pass1" }
    },
    messages:
    {
      fname:{required:"Please Enter Your First Name" },
      degree:{ required: "Please select an option"},
      branch:{ required: "Please select an option"},
      pass_year:{ required: "Please select an option"},
      roll_no:{ required: "Please enter your College Roll Number", minlength: "Roll number should be length 10", maxlength: "Roll number should be of length 10" },
      phone:{ required: "Please provide your phone number", minlength: "Phone number should be of length 10", maxlength: "Phone number should be of length 10" },
      email:{ required: "Please provide your mail address", email: "Incorrect Email Address" },
      present_address:{required:"Please provide your present address"},
      permanent_address:{required:"Please provide your permanent address"},
      facebook:{url:"Incorrect URL" },
      linkedin:{url:"Incorrect URL" },
      twitter:{url:"Incorrect URL" },
      github:{url:"Incorrect URL" },
      username:{ required:"Please provide a username", minlength:"Minimum length is 8"},
      password:{ required: "Please Enter password", minlength: "Minimum length is 8" },
      password1:{ required: "Please enter the password again", equalTo: "Password doesn't matches" }
    }
  });


});
```

Comment: You can get help from here : https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/  and 
 http://jsfiddle.net/xs5vrrso/

Answer (score 0):

Copy and Paste as it is. Hope it will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Register Yourself</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>NIT Uttarakhand</h1>
    <h2>Alumni</h2>
    <h3>Register Yourself</h3>

    <form id="register">
        <div>

            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"><br><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="mname" placeholder="Middle Name"><br><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"><br><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select name="degree">
          <option value="BT">B.Tech </option>
          <option value="MT">M.Tech </option>
          <option value="PH">PhD </option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select name="branch">
          <option value="civ">Civil Engineering </option>
          <option value="cse">Computer Science & Engineering </option>
          <option value="ece">Electronics and Communication Engineering </option>
          <option value="eee">Electrical and Electronics Engineering </option>
          <option value="mec">Mechanical Engineering </option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select name="pass_year">
          <option value="2015">2015</option>
          <option value="2016">2016</option>
          <option value="2017">2017</option>
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="roll_no" placeholder="Roll Number e.g., BT16CSE023"><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Mail ID">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="present_address" placeholder="Present Address"><br><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="permanent_address" placeholder="Permanent Address"><br><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook Profile"><br><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="linkedin" placeholder="Linked In Profile"><br><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter Profile"><br><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="github" placeholder="Github Profile"><br><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username (min 8 characters)"><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="pass1" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="password1" placeholder="Confirm password">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input class="btn-btn-primary" id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit Details">
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>






$(document).ready(function() {
    // Jquery form validator
    $("#register").validate({
        rules: {
            fname: {
                required: true
            },
            degree: {
                required: true
            },
            branch: {
                required: true
            },
            pass_year: {
                required: true
            },
            roll_no: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 10
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 10
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            present_address: {
                required: true
            },
            permanent_address: {
                required: true
            },
            facebook: {
                url: true
            },
            linkedin: {
                url: true
            },
            twitter: {
                url: true
            },
            github: {
                url: true
            },
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            password1: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#pass1"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            fname: {
                required: "Please Enter Your First Name"
            },
            degree: {
                required: "Please select an option"
            },
            branch: {
                required: "Please select an option"
            },
            pass_year: {
                required: "Please select an option"
            },
            roll_no: {
                required: "Please enter your College Roll Number",
                minlength: "Roll number should be length 10",
                maxlength: "Roll number should be of length 10"
            },
            phone: {
                required: "Please provide your phone number",
                minlength: "Phone number should be of length 10",
                maxlength: "Phone number should be of length 10"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please provide your mail address",
                email: "Incorrect Email Address"
            },
            present_address: {
                required: "Please provide your present address"
            },
            permanent_address: {
                required: "Please provide your permanent address"
            },
            facebook: {
                url: "Incorrect URL"
            },
            linkedin: {
                url: "Incorrect URL"
            },
            twitter: {
                url: "Incorrect URL"
            },
            github: {
                url: "Incorrect URL"
            },
            username: {
                required: "Please provide a username",
                minlength: "Minimum length is 8"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please Enter password",
                minlength: "Minimum length is 8"
            },
            password1: {
                required: "Please enter the password again",
                equalTo: "Password doesn't matches"
            }
        }
    });


});
```